# How do wizards hunt in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter

Wizards aren't allowed to use Unforgivable Curses, at least on wizards - can they use the Avada Kedavra on animals? They don't know what guns are. The only non-wand weapon that I've seen is Hagrid's crossbow, which I think he uses more for protection than for hunting.

Comment: [With their hands](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Snidget-hunting)

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Arrow-shooting_spell

Comment: [Accio](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning_Charm) bear! [Stupefy](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Stunning_Spell)! [Incendio](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Fire-Making_Spell)!

Comment: First you _Petrificus Totalus_ the animal, then you _Levicorpus_ it and bring it home, then you _Sectumsempra_ its jugular, and finally you un-petrify it. Easy-peasy. (Also, humans did hunt animals before they invented guns.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Levicorpus?  Shouldn't it be Locomotor [insert type of corpse]?

Comment: Weirdest thing I have typed all day

Comment: @CHEESE Yes. Yes, it should. Brainfart there.

Comment: Marked yours as the answer, lol. Forgot about this question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Wizards use their wands to hunt, but I don't think they use Avada Kedavra

We know that Wizards hunt with their wands

> He woke in a small shelter of branches and animal skins to find himself being nursed by Isolt. She could not hide her magic from him in such a confined space, particularly when she was brewing potions to aid the Boot boys’ recovery **and using her wand to hunt**. Isolt intended to Obliviate James once he was over his concussion and to send him back to the colony at Plymouth.
>   <sub>([Pottermore - Ilvermorny School of Witchcraft and Wizardry](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/ilvermorny))</sub>

The only legal issue with Avada Kedavra is when one uses it on a human. Animals should be fine.

> “Now . . . those three curses —  Avada Kedavra,  Imperius,  and Cruciatus — are known as the Unforgivable Curses. The use of  any one of them on a fellow human  being is enough to earn  a life sentence in Azkaban. That’s what  you’re up  against. That’s what I’ve got to  teach you to fight.  You need preparing. You  need  arming.  But  most  of  all,  you  need  to  practice  constant, never-ceasing vigilance. Get out  your  quills  . .  . copy this down. . . .”
>   <sub>--Alaster "Mad-Eye" Moody
>
>   (*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 14* - [text available on Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/book-extract-long/killing-curse-in-defence-against-dark-arts))</sub>

That said, I doubt that most Wizards would do so because a)Avada Kedavra was heavily associated with the Dark Arts and b)Avada Kedavra is a madly difficult spell to master

> “Avada Kedavra’s  a curse that needs a powerful bit of magic behind it — you could all get your  wands out now and point them at me and say the words, and I doubt  I’d get so  much as a nosebleed.
>   <sub>--Alaster "Mad-Eye" Moody
>
>   (*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 14* - [text available on Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/book-extract-long/killing-curse-in-defence-against-dark-arts))</sub>

So I would assume that they probably use their wands to perform other spells while hunting animals (such as stunning them).

Comment: Cool, and I think that further proof that it's only illegal on wizards would be the fact that Moody kills a spider in his lesson. Check.

Comment: @allies4ever - The only problem is that Moody later shows that he is perfectly fine with using unforgivable curses on *humans* during his lessons. So I don't think he would have cared even it was illegal.

Answer (score 6):

There is a deleted scene in the extras for *Deathly Hallows* Part 1 where Ron and Harry are chasing rabbits and shooting a nondescript spell at them. Presumably this is hunting - wizard style.

(I hope it's not just a mean game)

There is no green light, so it is not *Avada Kedavra*.

Comment: It's possible the green light hadn't been added in post-production before the scene was deleted.

Comment: Accio rabbit would have solved that problem.